# How to find out the reason for a failing elastic beanstalk deployment?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

After eb deploy the environment gets stuck in Health: 'Severe'.

It show the following warning in recent events:

> Environment health has transitioned from Info to Severe. ELB processes
> are not healthy on all instances. Application update in progress on 1
> instance. 0 out of 1 instance completed (running for 3 minutes). None
> of the instances are sending data. ELB health is failing or not
> available for all instances.

I'm not able to ssh into the instance: connection reset by peer. (I'm normally able to ssh into the instance without any issues).

The request logs function doesn't work because:

> An error occurred requesting logs: Environment named
> portal-api-staging is in an invalid state for this operation. Must be
> Ready.

Cloudwatch logs only contain the same message from 'recent events'.

How do I figure out what why the deployment fails?

AWS documentation says I should check the logs or ssh into the instance, but none of those options work.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I've been fighting with this for 3 days now.

Comment: I found my instance was running out of space during deployment. It was somehow leaving the instance in a state where I couldn't even ssh or otherwise connect to check the logs.

Increasing the disk size solved the issue.

Answer (score -1):

We found the issue. The deployment was somehow getting stuck and rolled back. Changing deployment policy to `AllAtOnce` and disabling `RollingUpdateEnabled` fixed it.